# What Path is the Babel Plugin module-alias Actually Using?

Tags: babeljs, proxyquire

I'm trying to use Babel's "module-alias" plug-in with the "proxyquire" testing library, but I'm not having a lot of luck.

**Library Backstory**

**(feel free to skip if you are familiar with both module-alias/proxyquire)**

Proxyquire let's you mock out a module's dependencies for testing, like so:

```
const someFunctionToTest = 
  proxyquire(pathToSomeFunctionToTestsModule, {
    pathToDependency: fakeVersionOfDependency
  });
```

Babel's module-alias plugin let's you make your import paths more convenient and consistent.  For instance, I can specify (in .babelrc):

```
"plugins": [
  ["module-alias", [
    { "src": "./", "expose": "~" }
  ]],
```

and then instead of having to type (when importing from a module nested three directories deep) `require('../../../someModule') I can just type`require('~/someModule')`.

**The Problem**

My problem is, they don't work together.  If I have`someModule` that depends on `someDependency`:

```
// src/someModule.js
const someDependency = require('~/src/someDependency');
doSomethingWith(someDependency);
```

and then I want to test `someModule` with a mock version of `someDependency`, I should be able to do:

```
const proxiedSomeModule = 
  proxyquire('~/src/someModule', {
    '~/src/someDependency': fakeVersionOfSomeDependency
  });
```

... but `proxyquire` tells me `Error: Cannot find module '~/src/someModule'.

Presumably ("behind the scenes") Babel is converting '~/src/someModule' into its real path, so when Proxyquire looks for the aliased path it can't find it.

**The Question**

My question is: is there any way I can find out what the real path of '~/src/someModule' is, after Babel converts it (ie. when proxyquire deals with it)?  Or alternatively is there any way to get proxyquire to just work with the aliased paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the "real" path (for `'~/someModule'`) generated by module resolver is just the `../../someModule` path. However, it also turns out that there is no need to convert paths by hand.

The module resolver plug-in will convert the arguments to any functions on its `transformFunctions` list.  This means that you can convert any string to its non-aliased form by doing the following:

1. Define a simple passthrough function, e.g. `const resolveModulePath = path => path;`
2. Add that function (along with `proxyquire`) to the `transformFunctions` list in `.babelrc`:

   ["module-resolver", {
     "transformFunctions": ["proxyquire", "resolveModulePath"]
   }]
3. Wrap any paths which aren't arguments to a function with `resolveModulePath`:

   proxyquire('~/some/path/someModule', {
     [resolveModulePath('~/some/other/path')]: {
         someFunction: fakeSomeFunction
     }
   })

Note that the first path in the above doesn't need to be escaped, as its an argument to a transformed function.  Only the second path (`'~/some/other/path'`) needs to be wrapped, because it's part of an object which is an argument; the string itself isn't an argument, until it's wrapped.

For further info see: https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver/issues/241#issuecomment-350109168